# Discord API forwarding a message from one webhook to another webhook

Tags: discord, webhooks

I would like to know if it's possible to forward a message received to a one webhook to another webhook

Does Discord messaging API supports this?

Comment: It's possible to receive a message (webhook) and it's possible to send a new message (webhook) using the content of the previously received message. There is no facility provided for forwarding (receiving and redirecting).

Comment: Do I have to create a bot to do this. Where can i intercept the first webhook in order to call the second webhook. How can i call it. Can you kindly point me to some resource on how to do this

Comment: Yes you are going to need a bot application in order to read incoming messages. I'm not sure what you mean by `where can I intercept the webhook call`, when the webhook posts as a message in a channel, your bot application would be notified by MESSAGE_CREATE event. You can intercept a message before it is actually posted. Your overall question or intent isn't very clear so I'm not sure how to provide any additional resources. You need to pick a programming language and then you can find a Discord API wrapper for that language and  check their documentation for further help in creating your bot